# Black corners around UITableViewCells

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am trying to display a UITableView in front of an image, and here's the steps I'm following:

- Inside the view, add a UIImageView with the image set to the appropriate file in the project
- Add a UITableView inside the parent view (the same parent as the image view)
- Set the backgroundColor for the table view to clear
- Wire up a datasource in the view controller to display some test data
- Hook up the data source in IB.

After doing this, the tableviewcells have a black background in the corners. It isn't coming from any of the parent views as far as I can tell. I have a test project at [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/khanzor/uitableviewcell-issue) which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: The root cause of why you need to set the clear color is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557856

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jeff Lamarche ran into the exact same issue today and put up a blog post about it:
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/08/transparent-grouped-tableviews.html

Basically, there appears to be some bug where you still need to add this in code (even though you already have the tableView set to be clear in Interface Builder):

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: another +1 :)  I owe you a beer.  You would have hoped Apple would have fixed this by now.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the black edges just go to ur .m file and in ur viewDidLoad method add a line

```
tableName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

and thats it no more ugly UI

Answer (score 1):

As stated in Jawboxer's answer, you need to set the background colour in code:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

But also ensure that the background colour in Interface Builder is set to the default "Group Table View Background Color". I had it as "Clear Color" in IB and it still wasn't working, until I reset it to the default.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of why you must set the clear color in code is here: [Black corners on UITableView Group Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557856)